# Why I can't set a parameter? The call looks correct

Tags: javascript

I am playing with [DMAK](https://github.com/mbilbille/dmak).

I want to remove the grid, and I see in the docs that the parameter is:

> grid.show - show or hide gridlines. true

So I call it like this:

```
var dmak = new Dmak('世界', "grid":{"show": "false"}, "stroke": {"attr": {"stroke": "#FF0000"}},"uri": "http://kanjivg.tagaini.net/kanjivg/kanji/"});
```

So, I edited the [library](https://github.com/mbilbille/dmak/blob/master/dist/dmak.js) and I set grid.show to false by default (line 83),

```
    grid: {
        show: false,
        attr: {
            "stroke": "#CCCCCC",
            "stroke-width": 0.5,
            "stroke-dasharray": "--"
        }
    }
```

but when I set grid.show to false (or true) on my call, it still shows the grid! It won't show if I don't set it

There's something wrong on my call?

I am trying to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the call is incorrect. You are passing `true` and `false` as strings `"true"` and `"false"`. A string evals to true.

Try setting it as :

```
 var dmak = new Dmak('世界', "grid":{"show": false}, "stroke": {"attr": {"stroke": "#FF0000"}},"uri": "http://kanjivg.tagaini.net/kanjivg/kanji/"});
```

and

```
var dmak = new Dmak('世界', "grid":{"show": true}, "stroke": {"attr": {"stroke": "#FF0000"}},"uri": "http://kanjivg.tagaini.net/kanjivg/kanji/"});
```

And it should work. Also now you don't need to edit the library which is a bad idea in most cases.